# Dynamically growing observableArray containing observables

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I'm aiming to have a dynamically growing list of input fields - whenever I start typing in an input field, a new empty one should appear beneath it.

I expected something like this to work;

```
function Model() {
    // Build a basic observable array
    this.inputs = ko.observableArray();

    // Whenever this changes, or on initial creation of this computed
    // add a new empty field if the last one has any text in it.
    ko.computed(function () {
        var len = this.inputs().length;
        // If there are no fields (initial run) or the last element is falsey...
        if (!len || this.inputs()[len-1]()) {
            // Create a new observable and add it to the array.
            this.inputs.push(ko.observable(""));
        }
    }, this);
}
```

Below is some basic HTML to bind the model to;

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: inputs">
    <li><input data-bind="textInput: $data" /></li>
</ul>
```

When I type into the text box that correctly appears (showing that this function does run on creation) the computed does not get invoked.

So what must I do to get the computed to reevaluate properly? Is there a better way to achieve a dynamically growing list that actually works in knockout?

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/311nsvv1/) of the exact code I have here, to help in debugging this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two reasons why the current implementation doesn't function as expected:

1. You're binding the input field to the `$data` context property, which according to the [docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html) is the string supplied to the observable. Bind to the `$rawData` property to bind to the actual observable.
2. [Computed dependency tracking](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-dependency-tracking.html) adds each observable it encounters during any evaluation run. Pushing a new observable apparently doesn't add a dependency. Initializing the observable array to a single observable would be a solution to this. By doing this, the `!len` check can also be removed.

```js
function Model() {
  this.inputs = ko.observableArray([ko.observable("")]);

  ko.computed(function() {
    if (!!this.inputs()[this.inputs().length - 1]()) {
      this.inputs.push(ko.observable(""));
    }
  }, this);
}

ko.applyBindings(new Model());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<ul data-bind="foreach: inputs">
  <li>
    <input data-bind="textInput: $rawData" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Below is an alternative routine. It is recursively adding an observable. When adding an observable, a subscription is created to track its changes. When it changes to a non-empty value, the subscription is disposed (it is only needed once) and the routine is repeated.

```js
function Model() {
  this.inputs = ko.observableArray();

  this.addItem = function() {
    var newItem = ko.observable("");
    this.inputs.push(newItem);
    var sub = newItem.subscribe(function(newValue) {
      if (!!newValue) {
        sub.dispose();
        this.addItem();
      }
    }, this);
  }

  this.addItem();
}
ko.applyBindings(new Model());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<ul data-bind="foreach: inputs">
  <li>
    <input data-bind="textInput: $rawData" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This seems like a good solution - but I'm not sure why the string is bound rather than the observable in my example. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I updated the answer with more details about why the current implementation didn't function as expected and updated the alternative with a slightly more compact version

Comment: ``$rawData`` fixed my implementation. Your other version does seem more efficient too - but I was thinking of collapsing things when they become empty, so I'll leave it for now. Thanks heaps :)